# How do I add a row at the end of each month that show the sum for each month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have pandas dataframe with index column having dates. And another column having some values.

```
Date        Value
2021-04-05   101
2021-04-12   200
2021-04-20   15
2021-05-21   12 
2021-05-28   11
```

I want to add a row at the end of each month showing the total for that month:

```
Date        Value
2021-04-05   101
2021-04-12   200
2021-04-20   15
April 2021   316
2021-05-21   12 
2021-05-28   11
May 2021     23
```

How do I do that? I know I will need to use groupby, that's not an issue, I use smth like this:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y'))['Values'].sum().sort_values()
```

But I don't know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the last of `Date` , then pass the `searchsorted`, and use the `sort_index`

```
s = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')).agg({'Date':'last','Value':'sum'})
index = np.searchsorted(df.Date,s.Date)
s = s.drop(['Date'],axis=1).reset_index()
s.index = index
s = pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index()
Out[729]: 
                  Date  Value
0  2021-04-05 00:00:00    101
1  2021-04-12 00:00:00    200
2  2021-04-20 00:00:00     15
2           April 2021    316
3  2021-05-21 00:00:00     12
4  2021-05-28 00:00:00     11
4             May 2021     23
```